# How to remove child from Expandable Listview

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Pretty much what i need is whenever a child is clicked i need an alert to appear asking if the person is sure to delete the reminder. If they press yes it needs to be removed how is that done? My code is below. So far with the solutions i tried nothing happens when i attempt to delete it. For example using `listDataChild.remove(childPosition)` does not work.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import Recycler.ExpandableListAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(); 

        Button home = findViewById(R.id.HomeBtn);
        Button menu = findViewById(R.id.MenuBtn);


        home.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_button);
        home.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_yes_select);

        menu.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_button);
        menu.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_not_select);

        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                home.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_yes_select);
                menu.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg_not_select);
            }
        });
        menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent MainToMenu = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(MainToMenu);
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);


            }
        });


        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


        //Expand Listview on Start
        expListView.expandGroup(0);
        expListView.expandGroup(1);
        expListView.expandGroup(2);




        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {


                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Remove Reminder");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this reminder");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

           //Need it Here!
                        

                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();


                return false;
            }
        });
    }


    private void prepareListData() {


        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Today");
        listDataHeader.add("Yesterday");
        listDataHeader.add("Older");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> TodayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        TodayList.add("Today Example");
        TodayList.add("Today Example");


        List<String> YesterdayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        YesterdayList.add("Yesterday Example");
        YesterdayList.add("Yesterday Example");

        List<String> OlderList = new ArrayList<String>();
        OlderList.add("Old Example");
        OlderList.add("Old Example");


        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), TodayList); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), YesterdayList);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), OlderList);
    }
}
```

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.test_list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.test_list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to call notifyItemRemoved(position) after you remove the item from adapter. Have you tried that?

Comment: @MehranB I earlier tried listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: can you share your adapter class as well please.

Comment: @MehranB Sorry i've done it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by moving on Click into `private void prepareListData()`. Then i added code which using child position and group position it got the text to remove from List Data.

The Code-

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {


                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Remove Reminder");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this reminder");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        
                        String ValueToRemove = listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);

                        TodayList.remove(ValueToRemove);
                        YesterdayList.remove(ValueToRemove);
                        OlderList.remove(ValueToRemove);

                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();


                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the selected group items list with **groupPosition**, then remove the selected item from the group list with **childPosition**.

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {


            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Remove Reminder");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this reminder");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    List<String> selectedGroupList = listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition));
                    selectedGroupList.remove(childPosition);

                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();


            return false;
        }
    });
```